# Databricks reading duplicate rows coming from Event Hubs

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have been trying to read some data in Azure Databricks coming from Event Hubs. On the first read, it reads the data correctly, but the problem is that when I send the same data or some different data later after some minutes or hours, it is reading both my previous and the new records. And I only want to read the new stream. I am stuck on this part that how can I only get to read the new records, and not duplicates.

The code I am using is written below. Please note I am using Azure Free Tier account along with Databricks community edition.

```
connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://ingestionlayer1.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=userpolicy2;SharedAccessKey=...=;EntityPath=dataingestion1"

ehConf = {}

ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString

ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = "$default"


import json
startingEventPosition = {
  "offset": -1,  
  "seqNo": -1,            
  "enqueuedTime": None,   
  "isInclusive": True
}

ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(startingEventPosition)


# Read events from the Event Hub
df_new = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()

read_stream = df_new.withColumn("body", df_new["body"].cast("string"))
#display(read_stream)


# Writing to Data lake

saveloc = "/mnt/streamingdatastorage2/datastorage2/Bronze/Table1"

read_stream2.writeStream.format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", f"{saveloc}/_checkpoint").start(saveloc)
```

I would really appreciate if anyone help me out with this !

Comment: do you write data somewhere? If yes, please add the code

Comment: Yes I'm writing the data to Data lake storage, but it is later after reading the data in Databricks. The duplication problem arises before writing, when I'm reading the data from event hubs. Though I have added the code.